# Counting threads of a Apache Camel route with custom components

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I would like to know if there is a good way to know approximately how many threads a route is going to use (at least in theory). Also, I am using custom components (some using singleton endpoints and some not). I don't want to use VisualVM at this stage, this is just for getting and approximate count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically each concurrent consumer on a single route will consume a single thread given all else the same. However, you could be using components that create their own threads internally and that would depend upon the component itself. However, you should be careful to count on that number because of the variants of the components. I would use a profiler to actually monitor the number in my running application if I wanted to get a good count for infrastructure allocation planning.